# In Oracle, how do I determine what audit settings are present for individual schemas?

Tags: oracle, auditing

I manage an Oracle database as DBA in my current role, but the database infrastructure including audit settings was defined by my predecessor, who I cannot contact.

I am trying to identify how my predecessor set up Oracle auditing. I suspect they configured auditing at a schema level with different configurations for different schemas. Is this possible?

If so, how do I see the different configurations for each schema?

Thanks

Comment: To check which tables are currently being audited, use the views DBA_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS and DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS. DBA_PRIV_AUDIT_OPTS describes current system privileges being audited across the system and by user.